# Message versus Signal for Method invocation in Sequence digram

Tags: uml, message, sequence-diagram, method-invocation

I am studying a UML sequence Diagram and I came across method invocation so, I have noticed that there are two ways to make invocation for the method-behavior in Unified Modeling Language(UML) which is signal and message but I don't know how to specify which one of them and based on what ?I mean When to use message and when to use signal because I think this is a very important design decision and should be well chosen?

Answer (score 3):

It actually is, but I think the terminology that you use is not very acurate (message and signal). All kind of communication between two objects in sequence diagram is considered to be a **message**.

However, there are two basic types of messages - **synchronous and asynchronous**.

A usual method invocation, when a method invoker waits blocked till the method execution is over is synchronous invocation, a synchronous message. The invoker will receive the return value from the invoked method and continue its own execution. 
In consequence, here is only one thread of execution.

There is also a asynchronous communication, when an object somehow sends a message to another object and immediatelly continues its execution without waiting. Example of this are SMS message, UDP package send, etc.
Here, there are two independent threads of execution.

By a **signal** it is often ment - asynchronous message send.

Answer (score 0):

Kirill Fakhroutdinov's page http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html explains message as

> #### Messages by Action Type
>
> ..A message reflects either an [operation](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html#operation) call and start of execution or a sending and reception of a [signal](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/common-behaviors.html#signal)...

Besides the **synchronous/asynchronous** nature of messages it also points to "send signal action" as used in activity diagrams

> #### Asynchronous Signal
>
> ..Asynchronous signal message corresponds to asynchronous [send signal action](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-actions.html#send-signal-action)..

To me an important distinction in modeling messages vs signals is the **unicast/multicast(broadcast)** semantics. Signal specifically can be send from one place (with all necessary arguments packed) and received at multiple places

Sequence diagrams allow modeling of the multicast behavior using the [found message](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#found-message) and [lost message](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/sequence-diagrams.html#lost-message) concept

(I'm not 100% sure but I believe I'm close)

---

**EDIT: adding reference to more formal explanation** backing my argument that signals have something to do with unicast/multicast(broadcast) as response to comment by @Aleks

The book ["The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual" by James Rumbaugh, Ivar Jacobson, Grady Booch, Copyright © 1999 by Addison Wesley Longman, Inc.](http://msdl.cs.mcgill.ca/people/tfeng/docs/The%20Unified%20Modeling%20Language%20Reference%20Manual.pdf) explains the difference between messages and signals e.g. using following words

> #### Message..Semantics
>
> ..A message is the **sending** of a **signal** from one object (the sender) to one or more other objects (the receivers), or it is the call of an operation on one object (the receiver) by another object (the sender or caller). The implementation of a message may take various forms...
>
> #### Signal event
>
> ..
>   A signal has an explicit list of parameters. It is explicitly sent by an object to another object or set of objects. A general **broadcast** of an event can be regarded as the sending of a signal to the set of all objects, although..
>
> ..
>   Signals are explicit means by which objects may communicate with each other **asynchronously**. To perform synchronous communication, two asynchronous signals must be used, one in each direction of communication..

**EDIT: adding the 3 different message notations** as they are visualized by Enterprise Architect

Note that due to the asynchronous and multicast nature of signals (as mentioned above) the corresponding notation does not include the "Return Value" part

[image: 3 different message types as supported by Enterprise Architect]

Comment: SIgnal (from the sequence diagram) and  send signal action (from the activity diagram) model excatly the SAME thing, the same concept, seen from the different perspectives. That's the whole bueauty of UML and power of abstraction - it gives us several options to model the same concept and we must decide and chose the best possible in each given context/situation. Lost and found messages on the other side are signals with the unknown sender or receiver, nothing to do with the broatcast.

Comment: @Aleks I agree that the signal classifier is perhaps in the model represented in a unique way and diagrams are just different points of view on different aspects of the system. I don't agree with "nothing to do with the broadcast" but this opinionated discussion would not answer PO's question about "Why there are two ways to make invocation..When to use message and when to use signal?". You can write what is right and what is wrong and what is beautiful in your own answer, which in my opinion does not answer the question sufficiently and that is why I tried to put down my own explanation

Comment: I think my answer should be sufficient to demistify the difference between the signal and sync-message. Understanding this difference, makes it easy to decide which one to use in UML diagram - when the nature of communication is sync - use sync message, when it is async - use signals. Plus, there are comments to further ask/clarify. :)

Comment: @Aleks I used your comments to improve my answer, thanks. BTW there are not 2 kinds of messages (as you claim in your answer and in your last comment) but 3 kinds of messages as shown on the picture